# How set example of value in input box of django form

Tags: python, css, django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to do the exact same thing as this has the only difference that the default text disappears when the user enters text

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="default value")
```

Exemple :

[image]

[image]

i'm using this method for my form

```
class Device(models.Model):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[0-9]{10}$', message="Error: Format 0611223344")

    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="default value")
    [....cut code....]

class DeviceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to use Django Forms' `widget` properties. Here, you can change the HTML that will be rendered client-side.

```py
class YourForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ('your', 'fields')
        widgets = {
            'form_field': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "Search Content..."}
        }
```

The above code will render an `input` tag for the field `form_field`, and add an HTML attribute of `placeholder` with the value of `Search Content...`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want a placeholder value on your field. Add the following code to your Form class.

```py
name = forms.CharField(
    label='Name', 
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type name here...'})
)
```